# Overstayed UK student visa in the past. Can I now visit the UK again?

Tags: visas, uk, overstaying

I was on a student visa in UK. My visa got expired and I overstayed 3 yrs more in addition to my visa. So in simple I stayed 3 yrs as illegal in the UK. Then I came back to my country deliberately. Remember I was never caught and deported. Is there any ban on me? Or is there? Will it affect my visa application for other countries. My passport is clean. There is no  exit stamp on it. Because it was expired when I came back and I made temporary travel document from my home country embassy. So am I eligible to travel to UK or other countries again?

Comment: If you have a ban you would have been notified in writing, so you're clean on that score.  If you apply for a UK visa you will need to lie about your overstay and that's a very risky proposition, especially if they can access where your embassy issued you a temporary travel document.

Comment: To clarify, you absolutely should not lie on a new visa application.

Comment: I removed the "trusted traveller" tag since there is no mention of it in the actual question to see how it could possibly have any relevance.

Comment: @Gayot Fow where on the form does it  ask you if you have ever overstayed?

Comment: @greatone Part 2, length of visit

Answer (score 6):

You can file a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration) to see what the government has on you.

This is NOT an endorsement, however, to lie on your visa application. That might get you in deep trouble. Remember: I am just a random Internet stranger rambling on a random website.

Comment: "I am just a random Internet stranger rambling on a random website" - or a UK Immigration Officer now on the lookout for applications from a "Mughees Ahmad" :D