# UK visas staying more than 6 months

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, overstaying

I have a 2 year UK visa, I stayed 6 months and 1 week I completely forget, will I have any problems when I come back in September?

**Update:** I tell you I have a visa two years but I stayed more than 6 months, 6 months and 17 days exactly, I am here with my fiancé I'm not working I would come back in September, have I a problem on my return?

Comment: I am not quite sure I can follow?  Did you overstay your visa and want to come back?

Comment: I still don't quite understand. You were admitted to the UK for six months? And you stayed longer than six months? If so, then yes, you will have a problem if you try to return.

Comment: I Stayed for 6 month and 17 days I would like to know if I would have problems when I come back in September or October

Comment: I have visas 2 years

Comment: @Batal That's abuse of your visa, they are going to be upset if they find out about it. You will not be able to get your visa renewed without deception. Bad position to be in.

Comment: @Berwyn the grace period is before a *mandatory* ban kicks in; the OP is still subject to removal from port if he's caught.

Comment: So u tink i Will have a problem when I want come back in uk or I have 28 day grace period??

Comment: @GayotFow: Understood. Deleted my comment

Comment: So im in big trouble what can I do please

Comment: My visas had not expired it remains more a year to me but i havé to exceed 17 days 6 months with it noticing stupidly there is no solution you think??

Comment: @Batal what was your reason for overstaying?

Comment: @Batal Yes you most probably will be in trouble at the landing interview for sure, if you don't have a very very genuine reason. Stay away if you don't want to be refused entry and put on the next plane back.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59164/overstayed-uk-student-visa-in-the-past-can-i-now-visit-the-uk-again

Answer (score 3):

By staying a full six months you have established you have no strong ties back to your 'home' country.

By not working while in UK you have established you were unemployed, so a risk for looking for income (illegally) while in UK.

By overstaying you have established you cannot be relied upon to leave the country of your own accord when required to do so.

By being with your fiancé, who presumably has the right to reside in the UK as you have not mentioned he too overstayed, you have given reason why you may become an illegal immigrant if allowed to re-enter.

By staying a full six months and more in UK you have somewhat exhausted plausible reasons (such as tourism) for a return after a short interval.

It is very likely that the length of your stay will be noticed and that you have overstayed. It is very unlikely that you will be allowed back in before expiry of your current visa and not likely you will be granted a further visa after a short interval.

If you do attempt to return under your current visa you will probably be refused entry and make it even more difficult for you to obtain a further visa for UK, or elsewhere.