# Previous Overstay seeking re-entry

Tags: visas, uk, study, overstaying

I previously overstayed as a visitor in the UK for 2 years and 7 months. I returned to my home country voluntarily at my own expense. i stayed out of the UK for 1 year and 11 months. i dont have an overstayer stamp on my passport. i applied for university in the UK and got accepted. There isnt a question about overstaying on a visa application so do i state the overstay on my own or answer only what is asked?

Comment: Does the application ask about the dates and length of previous visits? See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59164/overstayed-uk-student-visa-in-the-past-can-i-now-visit-the-uk-again

Comment: No there isnt a question about length of previous stay

Comment: The UKVI records have your immigration history which may affect the consideration of any subsequent visa application.

Comment: @Kmary The UK has collected exit data on all passengers since 2015 so they will certainly know about your overstay even if the application doesn’t specifically require you to disclose it. This example Tier 4 application guide from LSE indicates that previous U.K. travel history is requested (see page 14) https://info.lse.ac.uk/current-students/immigration-advice/assets/documents/Guide-to-EntryClearance-form.pdf

Comment: I am aware of being banned from the UK. Have i served that penalty time? What's your advice on matter, Should i get a lawyer?

Comment: My mother currently has Leave To Remain in the UK and i have a brother that is a British citizen. I am an adult but can anything be done by them to assist my application?

Comment: @Kmary your family in the UK are more likely to hinder your application than to help it, because the officer considering the application will see your relatives as potential reason for you to overstay in the UK.

Comment: I understand. Do you know of anyone who has managed to obtain a visa after serving the ban?

Comment: @Kmary Did you actually receive a ban?https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf Your question does not specifically say so. A condition of a student visa is that you will leave at the end of your studies, your history and having family in the U.K. may well be seen as indicating otherwise.

Comment: @Traveller No i didnt receive a ban. I assumed it was automatic.

Comment: Your chances are very very very very slim. Returning barely two years after overstaying. If you were a visa officer, would you reasonably give such a person a visa? You know the answer yourself.

Comment: The course i've applied for is for just one year with the support from a bank manager where i currently work. A one year visa isnt practical to you?

Answer (score 4):

You only need to answer what is asked but student visas are heavily scrutinized and the likelihood of you receiving one after overstaying is minimal.

I hope you didn’t spend a lot of money on the school’s application fee or send them a deposit.